# failed to resume in time on reopening when not in debug

Tags: iphone, crash

I am experiencing a rather distressing behavior. When executed from Xcode my app run and upon pushing the home button and restarting it works finely. Instead when I execute it on the iPhone, the first time it also work finely but when I reopen it, it freezes on the splash screen for some second and then crashes each time with a different log but always with message:
"AppName" failed to resume in time

Given that does not happen when threaded to Xcode, I do not think I may use Instruments: I also tried putting UIAlerts in the starting callbacks in the app delegate and main view controller but no one of them is called when it crashes.

What could it be and how could I target it?

Thanks, Fabrizio

Answer (score 1):

You can try profiling you application with Instruments to see what takes so long in your app that it fails to resume in time. Obviously, your situation assumes you have a different behavior when the app is debugged and when it is not, so the profiler might also fail to spot the issue, but you'd better try.

To work it out, do the following:

1. Connect you device to the computer
2. Launch the app and move it to background
3. Launch Instruments
4. Pick Time Profiler
5. Click "All processes" dropdown, choose you device and find your app's process
6. Start profiling
7. Re-open app

If you are lucky, you will see where the app spends a lot of time (maybe it is some kind of redrawing, maybe some re-initialization of a data set – whatever might be the reason) and this will lead you to the original cause of the problem.

Answer (score -1):

Strangely that only happen on my own iPhone: I tried it on another iPhone and on my iPad and everything was ok. That is therefore no longer a programming issue but a maintenance one.